# Error when deploying an app with Psynet: 'image_base_name is not a valid configuration key'

Tags: python

I'm using Psynet 4.0.0 with Dallinger 7.6. When running `psynet deploy`, I see the following error in the papertrail (the problem does not happen when deploying locally).

```
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   with open_text(package, resource, encoding, errors) as fp:
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1 Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/dallinger_heroku_clock", line 8, in <module>
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1     sys.exit(main())
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dallinger_scripts/clock.py", line 4, in main
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1     launch()
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dallinger/heroku/clock.py", line 49, in launch
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1     config.load()
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dallinger/config.py", line 279, in load
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1     self.load_from_file(localConfig)
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dallinger/config.py", line 238, in load_from_file
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1     self.extend(data, cast_types=True, strict=True)
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dallinger/config.py", line 133, in extend
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1     raise KeyError("{} is not a valid configuration key".format(key))
Oct 25 08:38:05 dlgr-ising-2int-long1 app/clock.1 KeyError: 'image_base_name is not a valid configuration key'
```

Unfortunately I am unable to share the full experiment code here due to privacy constraints, but I'm hoping someone has familiarity with the error message nonetheless.

Comment: Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that would allow someone to hopefully reproduce your problem. Then we'll be able to provide better feedback.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `image_base_name` is used in the context of Docker deployment. I'm surprised that Dallinger complains about it being present. Do you have `image_base_name` in config.txt?

Comment: Ah, maybe it should be called `docker_image_base_name` instead?

Comment: I agree, it's odd. I do not have any `image_base_name` in config.txt and I am not deploying using docker.

Comment: @PeterHarrison I managed to solve the problem by running `dallinger generate-constriants`. I think there was a mismatch with the dependencies in my virtual env   and those installed in Heroku.

Comment: Good to know. Please post this as the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Dallinger and Psynet versions were not set properly in my virtual env. I fixed the problem by running `dallinger generate-constraints`.